# VS2015 - Change TypeScript Version

Tags: c#, typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to update my Visual Studio 2015 + Cordova + TypeScript project to use TypeScript version to `1.6.0-beta`. I am currently using `1.5.3`.

I am able to use NPM to install the latest version, but my project continues using the old version.
`npm install -g typescript`

***How can I make my project use the latest TypeScript version?***

Locations of TypeScript Versions:

`1.5.3` = `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.5`

`1.6.0-beta` = `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm`

--------------------- Updated 9/4/2015 --------------------------

I updated the projects .jsproj file XML element `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>` to `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.6.0-beta</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`. I added the folder `1.6.0-beta` and NPM files to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript` and VS2015 doesn't use the latest TypeScript.
[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's the solution to upgrading TypeScript in Visual Studios 2015:

**Download the TypeScript EXE release from the following website:**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593
[image]

**Click the details to view other releases:**  In this case I want to download 1.6.0 Beta
[image]

**Download the exe and install onto computer.**

Create a new TypeScript Cordova project in VS2015.  VS2015 may ask if you want to upgrade the project to the latest version.  Follow the directions as necessary. 
[image]

**Updating Existing Projects**

If you have an existing project that needs to use a specific version to TypeScript, download the TypeScript version using the above steps, and modify the .jsproj file's XML element `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.6</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`. Set the number to the folder name located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript` folder.  The folder name represents the installed TypeScript version.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You can use `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>` in the visual studio project file  that changes the path to the TypeScript compiler.

So move your `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.6.0-beta\tsc.exe`

Comment: I wish stackoverflow.com search was better.  I spent an hour looking for this solution.  Searching bing, google and project source code didn't mention changing the .jsproj typescript xml

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for my Cordova project.  I changed the `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>` in the `.jsproj` and the updated TypeScript 1.6.0-beta intellisense doesn't work.  I can even removed the xml element `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>` and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe it's because when the project is open you need to unload the project before doing any correction. You can do that by right clicking on the name of the project in the Solution Explorer. After that, make the correction and reload the project :)

Comment: I found the problem.  I needed to download TypeScript for Visual Studio using this link [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593)

Once I downloaded and installed the exe, I could change the .jsproj XML and VS2015 would use the correct version.  Thanks for the help!  It focused me in the right direction!

Comment: @sbouaked's advice is good! I use typescript from npm packages + TypeScript version defined in <TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.7</TypeScriptToolsVersion>. I unloaded and loaded the project and it worked.

Comment: I wanted to use TS1.4 for VS2015. . Unloaded the project and  deleted TS1.8 folder . After that loaded the project again. But then I got stuck with error = 'TSC compiler exited with code1' .To fix that , I removed 'COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY' from C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets file . Again Reloaded the project. And it worked for me. Thanks @sbouaked . Your advice for reloading was helpful.

Answer (score 9):

**Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3<=**:

1. Right click on the project node in Solution Explorer
2. Click Properties
3. Go to the TypeScript Build tab
4. Change TypeScript version to the desired version or "use latest available" to always default to the newest version installed

**Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2>=**:

1. From the top menu bar, open Tools > Options > Text Editor >
   JavaScript/TypeScript > IntelliSense
2. Change Use TypeScript version to your desired version

I had a problem when updating that the version did not fall through. Fixed it by setting a lower version, shut down Visual Studio and then set the newer version. This fixed the problem.

[image]

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Updating-TypeScript-in-Visual-Studio-2017

Comment: Since last Saturday's update of 2017 (August 19) the version selection box in the screenshot has disappeared.

Comment: Its in the project solution properties now.  Its no longer in VS General settings.