# How to manage solutions that require different versions of typescript in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I've read about scenarios where a dev needed to downgrade their typescript in order for it to support a particular npm package version.

Can this be done with Visual Studio?  I recently downloaded a sample solution which used angular2 npm package.  The solution compiled without issue with the version of TypeScript that was installed in my instance of VS.  I think the previous TypeScript version was 1.8.2.

However, after I downloaded and installed the latest version of TypeScript in my VS the angular2 beta sample solution had compilation errors.  I think the updated version of TypeScript that I downloaded/installed was 2.0.1.

I could see a scenario where I have 2 different solutions: 1 solution which uses angular2 beta and 1 solution which uses @angular2 final.  I would need the latest version of TypeScript installed in VS to support @angular2 final but this means that the solution written in angular2 beta wouldn't compile.

Any idea how I would manage this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each project file can specify it's own typescript version. Though I'd recommend fixing the issues, providing a pull request, abandoning packages that don't stay up to date.

The Property in MsBuild that governs this setting is

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

See also:

- [VS2015 - Change TypeScript Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385087/vs2015-change-typescript-version)